# Value changes in Update column in Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I am using **liquibase** in my application. Here is my code snippet:

```html
- update:
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: is_active
                  value: Yes
                  type: VARCHAR
            tableName: vehicles
```

I am updating **is_active** column as **Yes** value. But it is inserting **true** in the DB. I am using **PostgreSQL**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used 'Yes' instead of Yes and the issue was resolved